# replacement for CSS variables in emails

Tags: html, html-email

From what I've seen CSS variables aren't compatible with a lot of email providers. Is there anything similar I could use?
I know there are frameworks like Tailwind that might be a solution but I would like to use pure CSS. Just want to find a way to easily change an image for example in several places.
What I want to accomplish is building a sort of template where I would use the same code just with a different main image for example, so instead of going into the code it would simply be on top of the file and I would change it there (for simplifying purposes)

Comment: Email clients don't all support HTML and CSS in the same way, and adding an entire CSS framework to your emails is unlikely to make things better. So, I'd suggest you're kind of asking the wrong question. Always start with what you want to achieve - why do you want to change the image in your email using css variables? Do you want your readers to see different images at different times of day, or based on their names, or what?

Comment: specified a bit what I want to achieve in the edit

Comment: Sounds a little like you're trying to make your life easier but actually making it harder! The simple solution might be to add a comment to your template `// CHANGE_ME` and then search to find the right location in your code when you need to change it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS preprocessors, or frameworks for building emails like [MJML](https://mjml.io/) or [Foundation](https://get.foundation/emails.html).

Comment: Adding [Maizzle](https://maizzle.com/) to the list here. Good framework that uses Tailwind in it's build process